# Gulp.js Concat - ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm having a problem setting up a basic Gulpfile.

My JS task does not work. I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
at Function.startup.resolveArgv0 (node.js:815:23)
at startup (node.js:58:13)
at node.js:906:3
```

What am I missing? I've tried setting the destination to various folders with no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var to5 = require("gulp-6to5");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var sass = require("gulp-ruby-sass");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var prefix = require("gulp-autoprefixer");

var watcher = gulp.watch(["./site/css/*.scss"], ["sass"]);

gulp.task("sass", function(){
    return sass("./site/css/", { sourcemap: true, style: 'compressed' })
        .on("error", function(err){
            console.error(err.message);
        })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./site/css/"))
});

gulp.task("js", function(){
    return gulp.src("./site/js/*.js")
        .pipe(to5())
        .pipe(concat("app.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("watch");

gulp.task("default", ["sass"]);
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error message with the line number pointed in the gulp file.

Comment: Full output would be better, including the command you run.

Comment: Had the same issue. In my case the 'clean' task was running at the same time.